# Sapply function in R

Tags: r

I have read two .csv files and did some editing.

```
a1<-read.csv("2013.csv",header=T, na.strings = c("NULL","PrivacySuppressed"))

a2<-a1[,441,drop=F]

a3<-a1[,-441,drop=F]

a4<-cbind(a1,a2)

a4<-a4[, colSums(is.na(a4)) != nrow(a4)]

 mode(a4)

[1] "list"
```

I need the a4 to be an integer so I used sapply

```
 s<-sapply(a4, as.numeric)
 mode(s)
[1] "numeric"
```

However, the problem is, the column names disappeared.

```
 names(s)

NULL
```

All the previous datas had column names. Sorry it is impossible to type here since there are 600 variables (600 different column names). I had names for my column until a4. After apply "sapply", the names says "NULL". When I just input s, I see the names of the columns but it is not detecting them as names for columns. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a question better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: Try `colnames(s)`, since `sapply()` returns a matrix.  And `as.integer()` if you want integers.  `as.numeric()` will not coerce to integer.  But probably what you really want is `a4[] <- lapply(a4, as.integer)`.  This will keep the data frame class, allowing you to use `names(a4)`

Comment: I tried the lapply function. s<-lapply(a4,as.integer). It did return back the column names, but it lost its dim(s) -> NULL.

Comment: So I just tested mode(a4) and it says "list". How can I change this into a matrix form or a data.frame? I tried functions like as.matrix or as.data.frame and it shows errors. Does "NA" values have anything to do with this? I got a few NA values in my data. I think that is the reason why mode(s) returns as "NULL".

Comment: Do you not want to override `a4`?  `a4[] <- lapply(a4, as.integer)` will do it.  Otherwise, `s <- a4; s[] <- lapply(s, as.integer)`.  You MUST use the `[]` brackets on `s[]`

Comment: Alright THANK YOU! I am trying to figure out the next stage which is fixing multicollinearity. Hope you can help me again soon :D

Answer (score -2):

I think the right command is:

```
a4 <- as.numeric(a4)
```